# Problem when posting comments

Tags: bug, comments

Ive had this every now and then: When writing a comment, and you start off with "@" you receive suggestions about whom youd like to adress. In some rare cases, when trying to adress someone who has a name containing a space, no suggestions pop up, and even wierder, editing a comment to add a @-tag at the beginning and saving does not modify the comment. Has anyone have had similar Problems?
For example, I was not able to adress User "Fly By Night" here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264976/48015
however, he was the one that created the post, does it have to do with that in this case? I have had the same problem is a few other locations aswell, I will try to find those.

Help with finding the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show to use where you got this ?

Comment: @NullPointer Im sorry? I added a link to an answer to that I couldnt adress the writer

Comment: looks like fine to me http://i.stack.imgur.com/0z7rx.png

Comment: @NullPointer then it is indeed a bug. I tried it just a minute ago and it still did not work

Comment: idk how its a bug ..when its working fine

Comment: related, possible duplicate [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/182513).

Comment: The easiest explanation as to why it is not working for you but working for NullPointer is that is the designed behavior of the `@replies`.  `@replies` are automatically removed (and do not popup automatically) when the comment chain is just 1 person plus the original poster.

Comment: Anyone with spaces in their names is just asking for trouble.